# Loading image in random position on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I am working on a portfolio website for my design work and I am running into a small problem.

I'm trying to load the images in random positions and then use Dragabilly to make the images draggable.

At times the images all end up in the top corner as if their position was not defined. Dragging around still works. I suspect this is something to do with not having the images completely loaded before executing the script, but I am not sure.

My site is live [here](http://nateasis.com/work/spar-stools.html)

And here is what I'm using...

```
$ ->
$('#menu-button').on 'click', ->
    $('#menu').toggleClass 'closed'
    return

if $(window).width() > 960
    $img = $ '.work-imgs img'

    wdoh = $('.work-desc').outerHeight()
    wl = ($(window).width() - 384) / $img.length
    wh = $(window).height() - wdoh

    $.each _.shuffle($img), (i, e) ->
        e.onload = ->
            rm = wh - $(e).height()
            $(e).css
                'left': i * wl + (Math.random() - .75) * 96
                'top': wdoh + Math.random() * rm
            return
        return

    $d = $img.draggabilly()
    $d.on 'pointerDown', ->
        $d.css 'z-index', 0
        $(this).css 'z-index', 1
        return

return
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BksIP.png)

Comment: The second line should be indented, and not aligned with `$ ->`, though I suspect this is a copy-paste error.. Is it in your code?

Comment: Yes copy-paste error, it's indented in my code

Comment: Well I can tell you what's not working: the `e.onload()` event you're binding isn't firing for every picture. And since they're all place in the top left corner on load, some stay there, sometimes. It may be a race condition between the global ready `$->` and the `onload` itself.

Comment: I agree with @ArcaneCraeda, the images could be cached, so they are loaded before the JS executes which means `onload` isn't fired. @Nate: you said sometimes it works. Did it work on the first try, and stop thereafter?

Comment: @LcLk correct, it works on the first try and doesn't after. What would you suggest the best way to cache the images is?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the images are cached by the browser. Well really this is a good thing, but it means that the `onload` event won't be triggered for all the images. Instead you will have to check if the image is already loaded when you assign the callback.

To check if the image is already loaded before the JS executes, you can use the `complete` property ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)).

```
    $.each _.shuffle($img), (i, e) ->
      callback = ->
        rm = wh - $(e).height()
        $(e).css
            'left': i * wl + (Math.random() - .75) * 96
            'top': wdoh + Math.random() * rm

      # if the image isn't cached, the onload will fire
      e.onload = callback
      # if the image is cached in the browser, and therefore already
      # loaded, you can run your callback immediately
      callback() if e.completed
```